# Pandas: replace value in cells from one column that match condition in other column using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Take the following sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['00100', 'Alpha', None],
                   ['00100', 'Beta', None],
                   ['05300', 'Theta', None],
                   ['95687', 'Gamma', None],
                   ['05300', 'Sigma', None]])
```

Which looks like

```
       0      1     2
0  00100  Alpha  None
1  00100   Beta  None
2  05300  Theta  None
3  95687  Gamma  None
4  05300  Sigma  None
```

I have a dictionary which maps the values for column 2 depending on the column 0:

```
match = {
    '00100' : '09010',
    '05300' : '09004'
}
```

I want to change the values in column 2 depending in the value from column 0. The end result I expect after matching the dict to the dataframe would be:

```
       0      1      2
0  00100  Alpha  09010
1  00100   Beta  09010
2  05300  Theta   None
3  95687  Gamma  09004
4  05300  Sigma  09004
```

At first I thought that I could make an .apply function or a for loop using .loc in the following fashion:

```
df.loc[df[0] == match[key]][2] = match[value]
```

But this raises an exception:

```
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
```

Which I can't seem to understand how to apply for this particular case.

I am using:
Python 3.6.1
Pandas 0.20.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. `pd.Series.map` takes a [function, dict, or Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
df[2] = df[0].map(match).fillna(df[2])

#        0      1      2
# 0  00100  Alpha  09010
# 1  00100   Beta  09010
# 2  05300  Theta  09004
# 3  95687  Gamma   None
# 4  05300  Sigma  09004
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
df[2] = df[0].apply(lambda x: match[x] if x in match else None)
```